# How to make Active Record join return unique objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple query need: Find a list of users who made an order since Jan 1, 2013.

In SQL, it's a very simple query.

But I'm using Rails and Active Record.

So I wrote: `User.joins(:orders).where("orders.created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'")`

In our database, we have 100 orders made since 01/01/2013 by 75 users.  (Some users made more than one order apparently.)

However, the expression above returns 100 users.  (There must be duplicates.)

I tried `User.joins(:orders).where("orders.created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'").uniq`

That doesn't work either.

How can I get the 75 users who've made an order since 01/01/2013?

Comment: What if you try to chain `select("DISTINCT(users.id)")` or `group("users.id")`

Comment: Do you have relations defined in your `User` and `Order` models? There is no need to use native sql

Comment: yes, I have relation set up between User and Order models.

Comment: @SergeyKishenin Thanks for the suggestion. select("DISTINCT(users.id)") would not work since I want the whole user objects (to access their attributes), not just IDs.  group("users.id") seems to work.

Comment: I had a similar problem. But I could do it by filtering the array with uniq_by and a block, which will keep the whole objects. I don't know if it will work in your case, but maybe try `users = User.joins(:orders).where("orders.created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'").uniq_by {|u| u.id}`

Comment: Try this - User.includes(:orders).where("orders.created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'")

Comment: When you join orders against users you can have duplicated records, because one user can have many orders. DB (or even ActiveRecord) doesn't know how to deal with these duplicates. Hence, you should take control on that. There are many ways to remove duplicates.

Grouping by users.id or sub-select like mentioned below can definitely help in this scenario.

In more advanced scenarios, when say you want to select some order data along with the unique user, a window function could be used with sub-select.

More info - https://blog.widefix.com/select-unique-latest-grouped-records-from-db/

Answer (score 83):

@dbjohn has the right idea, but I assume you want to avoid creating extra objects.  Here's a slight variant on his solution, letting the database do the uniq-ing for you:

```
date = "2013-01-01 00:00:00"
User.joins(:orders).where("orders.created_at >= ?", date).distinct
```

Note that you can rearrange the order of methods to fit whatever you think is most semantic, and ActiveRecord will write the same SQL for you.

Comment: Just want to point out for people coming here a little late, the sql query returned is

"select distinct on users.* from users inner join orders on order.user_id = users.id ..."

The important point being, it is distinct on the entire record, which might not be what you want.

Depending on what your exact use case is:

```
User.eager_loads(:orders)...
```
produces

"select users.id as x, ... orders.id as y,... from users left outer join orders on order.user_id = users.id ..."

With the benefit that the Users that are returned have the orders association _loaded_

Answer (score 19):

```
User.joins(:orders).
    where("orders.created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'").
    group('users.id')
```

`group` method will chain to the query and give you a list of unique records.

Answer (score 2):

You can write nested query like this:

`User.where(id: User.joins(:orders).where("orders.created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'").ids)`

Answer (score -4):

Rails has added `uniq` since version 3.2.1
so now you can use `uniq`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq

Comment: This is not the same thing as `distinct`,which uses SQL to narrow the scope which will prevent duplicate records from being instantiated, as of 5.1.1.

Comment: Also worth noting `uniq` is deprecated at of rails 5