# Apply NOT IN like condition on a model having has_many relationship with another, Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a use case to apply **NOT IN** like condition in where clause for a model with has_many association.

I have a **user** model that have a **has_many** relationship with **events**.

For getting all the users who have a particular event, the below code helps.

```
User.find(:all, joins: :events, conditions: [events.event_name = 'Event One'] )
```

I am searching for an optimal way to get the inverse of this done, as in to get all users who do not have a particular event.

Something like `User.find(:all, joins: :events, conditions: [clause to fetch all users who do not have event_name 'Event One' ] )`

Comment: how about changing into `User.find(:all, joins: :events, conditions: [events.event_name != 'Event One'] )`

Comment: That wont work since join is an inner join by default and the not equals check will be true for all other event_name the user has and will give the undesired results, say if the user_1 have ten other events and 'Event One' , this will return user_1 ten times even though user_1 has 'Event One' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that query with below

```
User.where("id NOT IN (?)", User.joins(:events).where("events.name = ?", "Event One").map(&:id))
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify query as follows:

```
User.find(:all, joins: :events, conditions: [events.event_name != 'Event One'] )
```

if this is not working then you can try something like below.

```
User.joins(:events).where('events.event_name != ?', 'Event One').distinct
```

Also you can check other alternatives to get uniq records [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230568/how-to-make-active-record-join-to-return-unique-objects)

Comment: Thais wont work since join is an inner join by default and the not equals check will be true for all other event_name the user has and will give the undesired results, say if the user_1 have ten other events and 'Event One' , this will return user_1 ten times even though user_1 has 'Event One'

Comment: you can use distinct on ActiveRecord::Relation to get uniq record, please check updated answer

Comment: Still user_1 should not come up in the result set since it already has an event named 'Event One', this is not supressing that.

Answer (score 0):

Query can be as follows:

```
User.joins(:events).where.not(events: { name: ["Event One"] }).all
```